# How to configure Tridion Logging for Linking with logback?

Tags: tridion

Tridion 2011 centralizes all logging configuration in the logback.xml file.  How do I configure the verbose logging of link resolving in Tridion 2011?

I do not think this is it, since it uses the DeployerLog.  Am I missing something?

```
   <logger name="com.tridion.tcdl">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingDeployerLog"/>
   </logger>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the linking info will - by default - appear in the cd_core.log, since this seems to be a "catch-all" log for all com.tridion.* classes.

You can add a log explicitly for linking as follows:

Create a linking-only appender:

```xml
<appender name="linkingLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/cd_link.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <prudent>true</prudent>
</appender>
```

Then bind the linking classes to this appender:

```xml
<logger name="com.tridion.linking" level="${log.level}">
    <appender-ref ref="linkingLog"/>
</logger>
```

if you want to use a different log level for this specific log file, then change it in the logger element.

Comment: Thanks Nuno.  This is exactly what I was looking for and missing in the default logback file.  Will be nice if this is included in the future logging samples.